# Problem with canvas size and aspect ratio

Tags: css

Basically I created a canvas with html and from the css I gave it a ratio of 16/9 and I put a width of 100ww, I also put a border, but the problem is that my canvas is bigger than what I see on the screen.

```css
#canvas{
width: 100vw;
aspect-ratio: 16/9;
border: 5px solid red;

}
```

I had to reduce the size and padding to compensate.

```css
*{

margin: 5px;

margin-left: 3%

}

.canvas{

width: 80vw;

aspect-ratio: 16/9

border: 3px solid red;

}
```

This works but I was expecting a full screen if you can say so

Screenshots:

[image: html]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try setting all default margins to zero * { margin: 0; } and set box-sizing: border-box

Comment: ```#canvas{box-sizing: border-box;}``` This would take care of the overflow due to the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dynamic solution to canvas size try this in your JS:

```
const canvas=document.querySelector("canvas")
canvas.width=window.innerWidth-canvas.offsetLeft
canvas.height=window.innerHeight-canvas.offsetTop
```

It'll set the canvas to the size of your window as well as compensate for any other elements in your HTML.
Also, add an event listener to reset the canvas size when you resize the window like below:

```
addEventListener("resize",function(){
    canvas.width=innerWidth
    canvas.height=innerHeight
    //INSERT FUNCTIONS TO CALL HERE!!
})
```

You'll need to call any functions that need resetting like ones that generate objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subtract the border from the width of your canvas, like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas{
  width: calc(100vw - 10px);
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  border: 5px solid red;

}
```

See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/ZEmjRxW

Note that I set the margin of the body to zero. If you have a non-zero margin you also have to subtract that.

Comment: I just tried it but when I put it to full screen in the browser the canvas dimensions are exceeded. Please review the screenshots

Comment: @NeonIO That's because of the vertical scrollbar. Note that you only set the width of the canvas, so if the screen is not high enough it wouldn't adjust to that. In that case use `max-height` to restrict the maximum height of the canvas. Clearly, in some cases it will be impossible to have a canvas at full width, be 16 by 9 and also fit in the height available.